# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'customgrid_grid_role' doesn't exist

Tags: magento, module, grid, editor, product

I've been successfully using the [Enhanced Admin Grids](https://github.com/mage-eag/mage-enhanced-admin-grids/tree/0.8.9) for magento extension for a quite a while so when I found out that editing the quantity is now supported in the latest version I automatically tried upgrading to 0.8.9 However I keep getting this error when attempting to go into the catalog:

`SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'buyahood_shopithoodies.customgrid_grid_role' doesn't exist`

```
Trace:
#0 /home/buyahood/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/buyahood/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/buyahood/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/buyahood/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT customg...', Array)
#4 /home/buyahood/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(389): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECTcustomg...', Array)
#5 /home/buyahood/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(734): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 /home/buyahood/public_html/app/code/community/BL/CustomGrid/Model/Mysql4/Grid.php(153): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
#7 /home/buyahood/public_html/app/code/community/BL/CustomGrid/Model/Grid.php(2254): BL_CustomGrid_Model_Mysql4_Grid->getGridRoles('1')
#8 /home/buyahood/public_html/app/code/community/BL/CustomGrid/Model/Grid.php(217): BL_CustomGrid_Model_Grid->loadRolesConfig()
#9 /home/buyahood/public_html/app/code/community/BL/CustomGrid/Model/Grid.php(223): BL_CustomGrid_Model_Grid->_refreshConfig()
#10 /home/buyahood/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(281): BL_CustomGrid_Model_Grid->_afterLoad()
#11 /home/buyahood/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(454): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->afterLoad()
#12 /home/buyahood/public_html/app/code/community/BL/CustomGrid/Model/Mysql4/Grid/Collection.php(27): Varien_Data_Collection->walk(Array, Array)
#13 /home/buyahood/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(536): BL_CustomGrid_Model_Mysql4_Grid_Collection->_afterLoad('afterLoad')
#14 /home/buyahood/public_html/app/code/community/BL/CustomGrid/Model/Observer.php(734): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
#15 /home/buyahood/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1303): BL_CustomGrid_Model_Observer->onControllerActionPreDispatch()
#16 /home/buyahood/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1284): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#17 /home/buyahood/public_html/app/Mage.php(416): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent(Object(BL_CustomGrid_Model_Observer), 'onControllerAct...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#18 /home/buyahood/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(505): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#19 /home/buyahood/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(152): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch('controller_acti...', Array)
#20 /home/buyahood/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(409): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->preDispatch()
#21 /home/buyahood/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch()
#22 /home/buyahood/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match('index')
#23 /home/buyahood/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#24 /home/buyahood/public_html/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run()
#25 /home/buyahood/public_html/index.php(82): Mage::run(Array)
#26 {main}
```

Please Advise.

Comment: You should contact this extension developers (support team) first. And if they will not be able to fix it, tell us what did you try to do to fix the problem.

Comment: Is your issue solved?

Answer (score -1):

This table should have been created during upgrade. Looks like the upgrade script didn't run. To trigger it again, edit the `core_resource` table. Search for a row with `customgrid_setup` and reset the version number to your version before your upgrade. After that, flush magento cache in backend. On the next page call the installer will be rerun.